# PHP preg_match and preg_quote doesn't match dollar sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to scan a string to check against a blacklist of words. I've used `preg_quote` to handle special characters such as an asterisk but it doesn't seem to work for the dollar sign.

Here is a test I've been running:

```
$string_to_check = 'wordcontaining$';
$naughty_words = array('wordcontaining$', 'a*differentstring');
if(isset($naughty_words)){
    foreach($naughty_words as $word){
        if (preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($word).'\b/i',$string_to_check)) {
            var_export(array('found'=> true, 'word'=>$word));
        }
    }
}
```

which I would expect to return

```
array (
    'found' => true,
    'word' => 'wordcontaining$',
)
```

but unfortunately it's not. If I set `$string_to_check = 'a*differentstring'` then everything works as expected.

Have I missed something very obvious here?

Comment: What `\b` is doing in your regex ?

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been a while since I coded this) it only looks for full words, i.e. if the blacklisted word appears in the middle of a longer word then it's not matched.

Comment: \b is a zero-width word boundary (I believe it's equivalent to `($|\W|^)`). Can you try exporting the result of preg_quote to see if it's escaping the dollar sign correctly?

Comment: @Josh - just keep first `\b` remove the second one & it will work fine.

Comment: Ah I've removed the second `\b` and it seems to work ok! Thanks Rikesh. Want to try adding it as a full answer so I can accept it?

Comment: but removing the second \b would make 'wordcontaining$aaa' valid. is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\b matches a position between a \w (word) and a \W (non-word)

\w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_] so $ and space are both non-word, so if the 'naughty_word' starts or ends with a symbol your expression can't match

you have to use something like

```
preg_match('/\s*+'.preg_quote($word).'\s*+/i',$string_to_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

So as per my comment above, you need to remove the second extra `\b` from your regex.

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Sm1R29)**

Comment: Unfortunately as per the comments above, this would also make 'wordcontaining$aaa' a valid word which is unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) which [automatically delimiters](https://t-regx.com/docs/delimiters) your pattern and [handles unsafe characters](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input):

```
if (Pattern::prepare(['\s*+', [$word], '\s*+'], 'i')->test($string_to_check)) {
```

*PS: `Pattern.test()` returns `true`/`false`*